# What is meant by a manifold identified with the boundary of another manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, manifolds-with-boundary

Recently, I've been looking into the topic on quasi-local mass. This is a topic related to general relativity, and I'd like to acquaint myself with it via the book titled *Geometric Relativity* and written by Dan A. Lee. Here's a definition in which a statement puzzles me much.

> **Definition 6.1.** Let $n\geq 3$, and let $(\Sigma^{n-1},\gamma)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold equipped with a nonnegative function $\eta$. We refer to the triple $(\Sigma,\gamma,\eta)$ as *Bartnik data*. We say that $(M^n,g)$ is an *admissible extension* of $(\Sigma,\gamma,\eta)$ if the following hold:
>
> (1) $(M,g)$ is a complete, asymptotically flat manifold with boundary $\partial M$ identified with $\Sigma$.
>
> (2) $R_g\geq 0$ in the interior of $M$.
>
> (3) The metric on $\Sigma=\partial M$ induced by $g$ is equal to $\gamma$.
>
> (4) Let $H_g$ denote the mean curvature of $\Sigma=\partial M$ in $(M,g)$, computed with respect to the "outward" normal $\nu$, which points into $M$. The mean curvature satisfies $H_g\leq\eta$.
>
> (5) $\Sigma=\partial M$ is not enclosed by an apparent horizon (except in the case $\eta\equiv 0$, in which case we allow $\partial M$ itself to be a horizon).

In condition (1), what did the author mean by a manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$ **identified with** $\Sigma$? The author did mention $\Sigma=\partial M$ a couple of times in subsequent conditions, but I still hesitate about whether or not the symbol $=$ is the ordinary equal sign (like the one in high school math). Could anyone please give me a conclusive answer? Thank you.

Comment: This is outside my area of expertise, but it appears that the author means that there is an isomorphism (in whatever category is appropriate... perhaps the category of smooth and/or Riemannian manifolds?) between $\partial M$ and $\Sigma$.  For all intents and purposes, these two objects are equal.  Philosophically, you might want to think of them as distinct, but from a practical point of view, I think that you can assume that $\partial M = \Sigma$ in the "high school" sense.

Comment: The above comment is the right answer. More precisely, $(\Sigma, \gamma)$ is isometric to $(\partial M, g|_{\partial M})$.

Comment: In this context, this means "diffeomorphic to."

Comment: @XanderHenderson You got it! I'm really worried about $\partial M\approx\Sigma$ or something.

Comment: I doubt if I can understand condition (3) without cracking this issue.

Comment: I have a slight disagreement with both Moishe and Didier.  I take "identified with" to not only mean that that $\partial M$ and $\Sigma$ are diffeomorphic, but that we have *fixed* such a diffeomorphism.  I'm not sure the distinction will matter in your context, but it can matter in some contexts.  For example, if you were to glue such admissible extensions along their boundary via the identity map (which makes sense after identifying $\partial M$ with $\Sigma$), then the topological type of the resulting manifold could depend on the choice of identification.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Yes, you are right, I was careless here. It does matter in this case since OP also wants to have an isometric embedding of the boundary to the ambient manifold.